# I can´t find the track and trace number in my json string

Tags: c#, json.net

I can´t find a value in a json string using json.net

I´ve tried `jsonstr[0].track_numbers[0].track_number`

This is my json file.

```
{
   "0": {
        "increment_id": "112",
        "track_numbers": [
        {
         "track_number": "2223",
         "title": "tit",
         "carrier_code": "custom"
        }
        ]
   },
   "live_shipping_status": "Delivered"
}
```

I want to find the `Track_nummber`.

```
dynamic jsonstr = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json));
var track = jsonstr[0].track_numbers[0].track_number
```

(donsent work)

Comment: Since it’s a key, does `jsonstr[“0”]` work?

Comment: You should read [ask].

Answer (score 3):

The `0` of your json is a string key, not an index position:

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
var trackNumber = obj["0"].track_numbers[0].track_number;
```

Note the difference in getting the first entry of `track_numbers`, which is an array.